# Perform Action When TabBarItem is Pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

How do I add an action to a Tab Bar Item when it is pressed. I've tried a few things, but either they aren't right, or I'm putting them in the right location.

In my storyboard, I have a tab view controller, which is connected to a navigation controller, and that is of course connected to a ViewController. I've tried using

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        //This method will be called when user changes tab.
    }
```

I added `UITabBarDelegate`, and it sill doesn't work? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you assign the delegate to the right class?

Comment: @KyleRedfearn Which class should I assin it to? The TabBarController, NavigationController, or the ViewController?

Comment: Assign it to the class that you implemented the delegate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom tab controller file and assign it as a custom class to your tab controller. Here's an example:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabViewController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("Selected item", item.tag )
}


func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    print("Selected view controller", viewController)
    print("index", tabBarController.selectedIndex )

}

}
```